# Illustrator Select multiple sub-groups within parent group

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

Is it possible to select multiple groups within a parent group using a selection tool?

I do NOT want to use the layers panel. I've been able to select a single sub-group within a parent group by using the Group Selection tool and clicking multiple times until the entire sub-group is select. However I haven't been able to use the Group Selection tool to select multiple sub-groups within the parent group having all sub-groups selected concurrently.

thank you.

Comment: You, can enter isolation mode for the group with doubleclicking black arrow tool then the things that were subgroups would now be groups so you can select them as normal groups. But theres nothing other than layers panel that can select sub sub groups that are in different branches...

Comment: Thank you. I've been using isolation mode. I will just make due now that I know there's no better way.

Comment: The "better way" is actually via the Layers Panel.

Comment: Of the two ways possible, Yes. But the interface isn't efficient.

Comment: Well, one could write a script to convert component selections to subgroup selections. Or make the toplevel groups layers and then everything would be easy.

Comment: I can't argue with "the interface isn't efficient". I tend to agree. Unfortunately, one uses the cards they are dealt.

Comment: To be hones ive never seen a super good solution to this problem. I mean maya comes close by allowing you to move in hierarchy with arrow keys. This allows you to select leaves and convert them to any level of hierarchy. The problem is how to make the computer understand that you dont want to select this but rather some nth parent of it or not the bottommost group but rather group under that group but nor group under group of group in a way that does not come in your way.